# Web Service App Crash That Doesn't Happen Too Frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

About a couple weeks ago, I submitted my JobSearch App to the App Store. This app uses the USA Job Search Web Service to get me the jobs in JSON data so that I can put those jobs into an array.

Anyway, my app got rejected due to a crash on the iPhone 5. I read the logs and they said

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

So I created an exception breakpoint in my application. It turns out if I enter random garbage for my input, the web service might return me 0 jobs, and sometimes it will return SIGABRT. I found the crash at this line of my code, where I'm creating an array to hold the service:

```
 NSMutableArray *jobsCallArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

I really can't find anything wrong with this code, and this is the only thing I need to fix to get my app accepted. If you would like to see how I call the service to it's entirety and all that, here is the code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"push"])
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.usa.gov/jobs/search.json?query=%@+jobs+in+%@", [jobDescription text], [location text]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray *jobsCallArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *positionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *theJob in jobsCallArray)
    {
        NSString *jobDesc = theJob[@"position_title"];
        [positionArray addObject:jobDesc];
    }

    FoundJobsTableViewController *detailVC = (FoundJobsTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    [detailVC  setArray:positionArray];
    [detailVC setTheUrlString:urlString];



}
}
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You are not checking anywhere to handle the condition if there is nil returned in JSON overall or in some category. Your code assumes that proper data is sent everytime

Comment: Also, try doing this:

NSDictionary *jobsCallArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];

Comment: If you don't use `error`, put `nil` instead. But checking the error could help and could be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for an error and whether you're actually receiving data:

```
if (!error && data) {
    NSMutableArray *jobsCallArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}
```

Comment: You are checking `error` before assigning the value to it

Comment: I'm assuming he's getting an NSError from whatever method he's using to make the API request.

Comment: I'm making the request in the prepareForSegue method. After running the app multiple times entering in random junk for the input as well as proper input, I am not longer getting any crashes. However, I don't think I have recreated the environment the way my app was reviewed.